# how to remove reference to .net assembly in matlab

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I have created a dll in c#. I added a reference to this dll in MATLAB as shown below. Everything works fine. The problem is that when I want to update my dll I have to close MATLAB otherwise I cannot rebuild my dll, which is rather annoying. How in MATLAB can I remove the reference to this dll - I thought there would just be a line of code to do this?

```
   % add reference to dll
   cls = NET.addAssembly('C:\MyFolder\MyDllFolder\bin\Debug\MyDll.dll');

   % reference my class
   mycls = MyNameSpace.MyClass();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `cls.delete` and then add the reference again?

I seem to remember `clear classes` being useful as well. Sorry I can't be more definitive, I don't have Matlab handy to set up an example.

**Edit**

Looks like I was wrong, according to this [link](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/limitations-to-net-support.html), "you cannot unload an assembly from MATLAB."

Comment: cls.delete didn't seem to do anything sadly. However clear classes does remove the variables from the workspace however I think MATLAB is still referencing the dll as I can't rebuild the dll in visual studio

Comment: after reading a matlab page, clear classes only removes the instances of the class

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you can start a **new Matlab instance** from Matlab itself with a system call and the [Matlab command line options](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html) and only load the libraries in the new instance. This is described in an answer to the qestion: [Release a .NET assembly from MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32617456/5276734)

Answer (score 1):

If the most important thing is the downtime while an assembly is being swapped, then you can do this without having to load a new MATLAB instance at all (which is very slow).

Even in pure .NET, it's not possible to unload an assembly from an AppDomain.  Too much state is affected by the JIT process -- bits of code from that assembly could have been inlined into many other functions.  This is actually one of the big reasons for having the AppDomain feature in the first place.

So, you will need a .NET assembly that acts as a wrapper and never changes.  Its function will be to create an AppDomain and load the assembly to test into that child AppDomain.  And, when it changes, to destroy the child AppDomain and create a new one.

It's complicated, but isolates MATLAB from the complexity.